# iPhone hotspot stops working and won't work again until the computer is restarted

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, wifi, tethering

I have an iPhone 12 mini running iOS 14.7.1 and a MacBook Air 13" 2017 running Big Sur.

The laptop and the iPhone are both signed into the same iCloud account.

The laptop can connect to the iPhone hotspot, but then randomly loses the Internet connection, despite still being connected to the hotspot. The laptop has an IP address still when this happens, and when I run a ping from Terminal it shows as a request timeout.

I have tried resetting network settings on the iPhone.

Most of the other troubleshooting tips revolve around restarting either or both devices, which is of course not idea as this happens pretty frequently.

I have tried enabling and disabling "Maximise compatibility" on the iPhone, I have tried disabling "Allow others to join", and it joins fine without a password since both devices are on the same iCloud account.

Lots of people appear to have the same issue but there are no clear solutions and any solutions that appear to have worked for others haven't worked for me (and even on those solutions I can see they haven't worked for others which sort of suggests it might have been a coincidence that they worked at all).

The only thing that definitely works every time is rebooting the laptop but I really dislike having to do that so often.

Any ideas about how to fix it permanently?

Comment: Maybe you can try connecting to the hotspot via USB. That's how I do it and I've never faced this issue.

Comment: Then I would have to carry around a USB cable and I wouldn't feel like a futuristic hipster. It would totally kill the vibe.